# Powershell /c with Special Characters (PsExec/EncodedCommand)

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, psexec

I'm trying to configure [autologon.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon) using the command line (via PsExec). However, the special characters in the password are causing issues.

Given this password: `I'vegotspe"cia"char@ters`

This command works:

`Start-Process 'C:\Autologon.exe' -ArgumentList 'username','hostname','"I''vegotspe\"cia\"char@ters"','/accepteula'`

However since I'm using PsExec the I need to make the call with "/c" so I have the following command.

```
powershell.exe /c  "Start-Process 'C:\Autologon.exe' -ArgumentList 'username','hostname','"I''vegotspe\"cia\"char@ters"','/accepteula'"
```

This command doesn't output any errors but it doesn't work either. It works if I don't have the double-quote character. Any idea how I can make this work?

I'm using [PyPsexec](https://pypi.org/project/pypsexec/) so once I get the above command working; the call would look like this

```
c.run_executable("powershell.exe", arguments=''' /c Start-Process 'C:\Autologon.exe' -ArgumentList 'username','hostname','"I''vegotspe\"cia\"char@ters"','/accepteula' ''')
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Just tried the EncodedCommand as @lit suggested but I seem to have the same syntax issue since it needs to be wrapped in quotations.

COMMAND:

```
[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("Start-Process 'C:\Autologon.exe' -ArgumentList 'username','hostname','"I''vegotspe\"cia\"char@ters"','/accepteula'"))
```

OUTPUT:

```
ine:1 char:140
+ ... ess 'C:\Autologon.exe' -ArgumentList 'username','hostname','"I''vegot ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:140
+ ... username','hostname','"I''vegotspe\"cia\"char@ters"','/accepteula'"))
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'I''vegotspe\"cia\"char@ters"','/accepteula'"' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:184
+ ... username','hostname','"I''vegotspe\"cia\"char@ters"','/accepteula'"))
+                                                                        ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:185
+ ... username','hostname','"I''vegotspe\"cia\"char@ters"','/accepteula'"))
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

Comment: The `/c` parameter is `-Command`. It is not clear how `psexec` is used. Is this `psexec` from the SysInternals kit? Why are `psexec` and `powershell` being used? See also the powershell `-EncodedCommand` parameter.

Comment: It is the same PsExec but a python library (PyPsExec) exists to make it easier to incorporate in scripts. PsExec is used so I can remotely execute this command and Powershell is used to make the call to Autologin.

Comment: Just tried the encoded command (updated the original question with results)

Comment: so is the target a Windows box? Or the source, I suppose. Is there a reason you're not simply doing a remote `Invoke-Command`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest storing the password in a variable. Then use the call operator `&`. That may work better than trying to pass a wierd string.

```
& C:\Autologon.exe /accepteula username hostname $password
```

It might help to put *all* the arguments in variables, depending on how `/accepteula` goes.

But if you're going to run it from your psexec equivalent - which implies it's using the command interpreter - why the Powershell?

Perhaps the complex password is no good if you simply run it on a command line - I don't know if you've tested it. It might make life easier to simplify it so it's a long string with "enough" complexity. Or you could can set a variable for your password using the `SET` command.

```
set PWD=I'vegotspe"cia"char@ters"
C:\Autologon.exe /accepteula username hostname %PWD%
```

It might need a `CMD /C` before the executable, depending on how your Python thing works. No point adding extra interpreters like Powershell if you don't need them.